# Facebook and twitter Social Network ID

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, twitter, social-networking, instagram

I have a simple question but could not find answer. Question is that does every account on social website or application have unique social network id. I did found that Facebook users have unique social id but can two different users on different social applications have same social network id.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually a users unique id would be unique only to it's application. So if you have an account on Facebook you have a user id that is unique to Facebook, if you have an account on Twitter then you have a user id that is unique to Twitter.

Some 'networks' allow you to join or log-in using an account from Facebook/Google/Twitter, etc.. In this case I believe your details are merely (for lack of better word) *linked* to a new user id on the new site you joined, it just appears you're on your Facebook or whichever account.

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your questions.
Yes, every user on every social account have a unique id.
Yes (but very unlikely), two different user on two different social websites can have the same id, I get you are asking since you want to store the id in your database, right? :)

Then there is ieedee.com, that gathers all of your id's on one place. One id, for all id's :)